# How to remove label text in detected image YOLOv8?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I don't understand how to remove label text in detected image in YOLOv8 using code from ultralytics github https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics. I'm still newbie

I expecting can remove label text in detected image in YOLOv8

Comment: Please add some code , or explain your problem with an example

Answer (score 1):

You may use below command parameters in your python script

```
model.predict( source="image.jpg", show=True, hide_labels=True, hide_conf=True, conf=0.3)
```

Or in the cmd console:

```
yolo source=img.jpg hide_labels=True ...
```

Comment: I know hide_labels and hide_conf are officially documented. Does it actually work for you? Tried it on my end and I still see labels and confs being displayed. Is this a bug? 



```
results = model.predict(
    image,
    conf=conf,
    iou=iou,
    hide_labels=True,
    hide_conf=True,
)

render = render_result(model=model, image=image, result=results[0])
render.show()
```